# Which union is more efficient: List / HashSet

Tags: java, scala, collections

I'm writing some algorithem where I need to use a collection, and the main (and only) action with them is union.

I'm going to have about **1 million** objects, and I need to know which collection has the more efficient union method - *The list or the HashSet* (ot maybe something else?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first one may have duplicates, the other, no. You should also choose according to this criteria.

Comment: I will be using 'distinct' with the list.

Comment: There are many (potentially unlimited) implementations of list, so making a comparison is not really possible. Are you basically wanting to add two collections together elimitating duplicates? Hashset is going to eliminate the duplicates automatically using its .contains method and hashset has a fast contains. But this is surely easy to profile, do both and use the one that is faster

Comment: Indeed scala. I can check run times but on the paper, which one is nore efficient?

Comment: HashSet.contains is O(1). List.contains is O(n).

Comment: Ok, yeah. But how about union? Whats that? O(?)

Comment: Btw why have you tagged both scala and java? Do you want a java answer or a scala answer?  I know scala is on the jvm and can reach out to java but that's true of every single scala question

Comment: How do you create the union of two collections? You add everything from collection A to collection B unless the element is already contained in B, right? So, you have your answer.

Comment: So the both of the unions are the same O(N) (n - size of the second collection)?

Comment: How are the keys distributed - is it possible to have a compact representation of the key set? How will the union operation be executed? Create a third set C from A u B, or A = A u B?

Comment: Lauene - every set will have about 100 Integers. And I can create a new set or adding to an existing one - I need the more efficient option. What do you think?

Comment: @user8794683. No, of course not. You need to call B.contains() for each element of A. Each contains is O(N) is B is a List, and O(1) is A is a Set. So the whole operation will be O(N*M) for a List and O(M) for HashSet.

Comment: How do the "about 100 integers" relate to the "1 million objects"? - What one needs to know is whether the set elements are within a range for each set, the quality of these ranges, how many sets you'll have concurrently,...

Comment: We need more context. If performance is your primary concern your best bet could well be using `BitSet`'s `or` method.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that when you say "I will be using `distinct` with the List", you mean something like this:

```
  List l = ...
  Set result = Collectors.toSet(l.stream().distinct()).union(someOtherSet);
```

compared with this:

```
  HashSet h = ...
  Set result = h.union(someOtherSet);
```

Clearly the second version is more efficient.  The first one has to produce an intermediate set from the list.  Each time you run it.

The only thing that the first one saves is some memory (in the long term), since the intermediate set becomes unreachable after use.

And the first version can be written more simply and more efficiently as:

```
  List l = ...
  Set result = new HashSet(l).union(someOtherSet);
```

The List API has no `distinct()` method and no `union()` method.

---

If you actually use `Collection.contains()` to perform the union, then a `HashSet()` will be much faster than any standard `List` implementation. As @JBNizet states:

> HashSet.contains is O(1). List.contains is O(n).

For example:

```
  Set result = new HashSet();
  for (Integer element: set1) {
      if (set2.contains(element)) {
          result.add(element);
      }
  }
  // result now contains the union of set1 and set2.
```

Almost identical code works for lists.   But it is *much* slower.

You asked:

> Ok, yeah. But how about union?

See above.  This is about implementing `union` using `contains` calls.

> Whats that? O(?)

See the following articles:

- https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

> So the both of the unions are the same O(N) (n - size of the second collection)?

No.

- Using HashSet: `N x O(1)` is `O(N)`
- Using List: `N x O(N)` is `O(N^2)`

Or to be more precise:

- Using HashSet: `min(M, N) x O(1)` is `O(min(M, N))`
- Using List: `N x O(M)` is `O(NM)`

where N and M are the sizes of the two sets / lists.  You can tweak the performance of the `HashSet` case by iterating the smaller of the two sets. as reflected above.

---

Finally, if the element type is `Integer` then `Bitset` could be more efficient than either `List` or `HashSet`.  And it could use a couple of orders of magnitude less memory!   Depending on the *range* of the integers, and the *density* of the sets.

---

That's the Java analysis.  I'm not familiar with Scala but the underlying computations and complexity will be the same.